Closed embedding are affine morphisms
$\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr O}$$\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$$\newcommand{\V}{\mathbb V}$
Ok, I have been through the ringer with this problem today and I think I am finally on the right track, but for some reason proving this has been more difficult than anticipated.
Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a closed embedding of schemes, by which I mean the topological map $f$ is a homeomorphism onto a closed subset of $Y$, and $f^\sharp:\O_Y\rightarrow f_*\O_X$ is a surjective morphism of sheafs. I am trying to show that if $U=\Spec A\subset Y$ is affine then $f^{-1}(U)\cong \Spec A/I$ for some $I\subset A$.
Let $I_{X/Y}$ be the sheaf of ideals on $Y$ given by $I_{X/Y}=\ker f^\sharp$. If $U=\Spec A\subset Y$ is affine, then $I_{X/Y}(U)$ is an ideal $I\subset A$. If we let $V=f^{-1}(U)$ then we obtain a morphism of schemes $f|_V:V\rightarrow U$ which must be a closed embedding of schemes as $f|_V$ is a homeomorphism onto $U\cap f(X)$ and the surjection property is inherently local. Now a priori, we don't know that $V$ is affine, but we do now that every morphism from a general scheme to an affine one is induced by the morphism on its ring of global sections. In particular, if $\psi:A\rightarrow \O_V(V)$ is our short hand for the morphism $(f|_V)^\sharp_U$, then the topological map $f|_V$ is given by:
$$f|_V(x)=\psi^{-1}(\pi^{-1}_x(\mathfrak m_x))$$
where $\pi_x$ is the ring homomorphism $\O_V(V)\rightarrow( \O_V)_x$ and $\mathfrak m_x\subset (\O_V)_x$ is the unique maximal ideal of the stalk. It is then clear that $f|_V$ has image in $\V(I)\subset \Spec A=U$ as $I=\ker\psi$ and $0\in \mathfrak m_x$ so $\psi^{-1}(0)=\ker\psi=I\subset f|_V(x)$.
Where my trouble is is showing that $\V(I)\subset f|_V(V)$. In particular, I think this where I should invoke the surjectivity of $(f_V)^\sharp_{\mathfrak p}$ but I am not sure how...given a prime ideal such that $I\subset \mathfrak p$ I need to find an $x\in V$ such that $f|_V(x)=\mathfrak p$ but I am not sure how to do this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated; once I can show this homeomorphism I think I will be golden because I have an idea for how to construct the sheaf isomorphism to $\O_{\Spec A/I}$.

It's equivalent and easier to work with $Y$ being affine right off the bat

@FShrike Sure, but it doesn't really change where I'm having issue as I reduced to that case quickly

You can also say $Z$ is isomorphic as a ringed space to the ringed space $(V(\ker f#),O/\ker f#)$ and then it just has to be argued this is an affine scheme of the expected form. Iirc there's some subtlety with closed subsets not having a unique subscheme structure and needing to take radicals and reductions everywhere

@FShrike that is harder to prove as you actually need $i^{-1}O/\ker f^\sharp$ otherwise your sheaf is on the wrong topological space.

Ok I've made an answer, I've tried to align it with your ideas and highlight the main points. Hopefully it is more helpful; I did not just copy this from an alg. geo textbook :)

Is there anything you would like me to improve upon in my answer?

@FShrike no sorry I meant to accept and just forgot. It was very helpful!

Oh no worries - I wasn't fishing for an acceptance, was just wondering if I'd overdone it or something.. ; )

$\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}\newcommand{\V}{\mathbb{V}}\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}$Seeing what you want to see unfortunately involves a slightly subtle point where we require $Z$ to be a scheme and use an affine basis. We can't argue purely with the theory of locally ringed spaces. I go about it slightly differently, determining $Z$ as the support $\V(\J)$ of an appropriate sheaf and viewing the calculation $\J=\ker\varphi$ as the main point; I think it is harder to first define $\J=\ker\varphi$ and then try to compute that $\V(\J)=Z$ and identify $\O_Z$ with the quotient by $\J$.
If $\iota:(Z;\O_Z)\hookrightarrow(X;\O_X)$ is a closed immersion of schemes we know $\J=\ker\iota^\#$ is the important thing and - which seems to be the part you didn't get yet - $\V(\J)=Z$, by the general nonsense at the bottom. Suppose $X$ is affine.
Using your nice idea about the spec-global adjunction (valid for locally ringed spaces in general) we can write $\iota$ as the composite: $$\iota:Z\overset{\eta}{\longrightarrow}\spec B\overset{\spec\varphi}{\longrightarrow}\spec A$$Where $A:=\O_X(X),B:=\O_Z(Z)$, $\varphi=\iota^\#_X$ and $\eta$ is the adjunction unit.
We would love to say $\J$ is isomorphic with the sheaf of ideals associated to $\ker\varphi:=\I$. Then $\V(\J)=\V(\I)\cong\spec A/\I$ (using two 'different' notions of $\V$ and $\cong$ is a homeomorphism of spaces) and under this homeomorphism we could easily identify $j^\ast(\O_X/\J)\cong\O_{\spec A/\I}$ since localisation of rings commutes with quotients. Thus $Z\cong\spec A/\I$ as a scheme, underneath $X$, would follow as desired. Make sure you can check $\V(\widetilde{\I})$ - in the sense of the vanishing set of a sheaf of ideals, defined in the bottom section - really is equal to $\V(\I)=\{\mathfrak{p}\in\spec A:\mathfrak{p}\supseteq\I\}$.
To determine $\J\cong\widetilde{\I}$ we just need to check (using the nature of $\eta,\spec\varphi$) that $\I_f$ is the kernel of $A_f\to B_{\varphi(f)}=\O_Z(Z)_{\varphi(f)}\to\O_Z(Z_{\varphi(f)})$ for all $f\in A$. This is $\iota^\#=\eta^\#(\spec\varphi)^\#$'s action on the principal affine open $D(f)$. The exact sequence of $A$-modules $0\to\I\to A\to B$ certainly tells you after localisation that $\I_f$ is the kernel of $A_f\to B_{\varphi(f)}$; thus, the game is to determine that $\O_Z(Z)_{\varphi(f)}\to\O_Z(Z_{\varphi(f)})$ is necessarily injective.
Well, it sure would be an injective map (isomorphism/equality) if $Z$ were affine so here is where we have to use the fact $Z$ locally looks like an affine scheme:
$X$ is compact, so so is $Z$. $Z$ thus admits a finite cover by affine opens $U_1,\cdots,U_n$ (more precisely we require $(U_\bullet;\O_Z|_{U_\bullet})$ is affine). This is the only place where we use the assumption $Z$ is a scheme rather than an arbitrary locally ringed space. We have a commutative diagram, with $g:=\varphi(f)$: $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}\O_Z(Z)_g@>>>\O_Z(Z_g)\\@VVV@VVV\\\bigoplus_{k=1}^n\O_Z(U_k)_g@>>\cong>\bigoplus_{k=1}^n\O_Z(U_k\cap Z_g)\end{CD}$$Where the vertical maps are injective by the separatedness property of a sheaf and exactness of localisation (which commutes with finite direct products) and the bottom map is an isomorphism because the $U_\bullet$ are affine.
It follows the top map is injective, as desired, so $\I_f\hookrightarrow A_f$ really is identifiable with $\J=\ker\iota^\#$. For we have just constructed an isomorphism between the two on the basis of principal affine opens $(D(f))_{f\in A}$, a basis for $X$, so by general sheaf theory these sheaves must be isomorphic and we win.

A generic lemma that has nothing to do with schemes per se, just locally ringed spaces: Say $(X;\O_X)$ is a locally ringed space and $\J$ is a sheaf of ideals on $X$. We first claim $(\V(J);j^\ast(\O_X/\J))$ is a locally ringed space, where $\V(\J):=\{x\in X:\J_{X,x}\neq\O_{X,x}\}$, where $j:\V(J)\hookrightarrow X$. Firstly we must convince ourselves $j^\ast$ of a sheaf of rings is again a sheaf of rings in such a way that the unit/counit of adjunction are (local) ring homomorphisms. This is fairly clear. The reason it is a locally ringed sheaf is because each stalk is isomorphic with $\O_{X,x}/\J_{X,x}$ and if $A$ is a local ring and $I\subset A$ a proper ideal (this is the only reason we need to restrict to $\V$) then $A/I$ is also a local ring. Now, say $\iota:(Z;\O_Z)\hookrightarrow(X;\O_X)$ is a closed immersion of locally ringed spaces. If $\J=\ker\iota^\#$ we would want to identify $(Z;\O_Z)\cong(\V(\J);j^\ast(\O_X/\J))$ underneath $X$. First note for $x\in X\setminus Z$ that $(\iota_\ast\O_Z)_x=0$ by closedness, thus $\J_x=\O_{X,x}$. Now if $z\in Z$ then we are given, by the surjectivity condition, that: $$0\to\J_z\to\O_{X,z}\to\O_{Z,z}\to0$$Is exact; as $\O_Z$ is a locally ringed sheaf $\O_{Z,z}\neq0$ and it follows $\J_z$ is a proper ideal of $\O_{X,z}$. Therefore $\V(\J)=Z$ as an exact equality of subspaces of $X$ and $j=\iota$ on the point-set level. Moreover: $$0\to j^\ast\J\to j^\ast\O_X\to\O_Z\to0$$Is an exact sequences of sheaves on $Z$ and $j^\ast$ preserves quotients so $\O_Z\cong j^\ast(\O_X/\J)$ compatibly w.r.t $X$, as desired.
